# AWS Stepfunction & ApiGateway Dynamic path (path parameter)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, state-machine, aws-step-functions

On my api I have a route with a path parameter: `api.com/item/{id}` I cannot generate the path directly from the stpefunction. I tried to concatenate the static part and the dynamic part using the intriseque function but I got this error: `Reference path didn't start with '$'`  and I did not find any parameter to enter a path parameter in the doc

```json
{
  "Comment": "Stepfunction",
  "StartAt": "Generate random ID",
  "States": {
    "Generate random ID": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "${GetRandomFunctionArn}",
      "ResultPath": "$",
      "Next": "Get item"
    },
    "Get item": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::apigateway:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "ApiEndpoint": "${APIBaseUrl}",
        "Method": "GET",
        "RequestBody": {},
        "AuthType": "NO_AUTH",
        "Stage": "${APIStage}",
        "Path": "States.Format(${EndpointProductAvailability}/{}, $.item_id)"
      },
      "End": "True"
    }
  }
}
```

The stepfunctin is part of a sam application.

How to make an api call with one part which is an input variable and the rest which is generated by a previous task?

Comment: You might need to set .$ after Path: `"Path.$": "States.Format(${EndpointProductAvailability}/{}, $.item_id)"`.

Comment: I try too but i have the same error ...

Answer (score 1):

You path should be something like this:

As per this [AWS Step Functions adds updates to ‘choice’ state, global access to context object, dynamic timeouts, result selection, and intrinsic functions to Amazon States Language](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-step-functions-adds-updates-to-choice-state-global-access-to-context-object-dynamic-timeouts-result-selection-and-intrinsic-functions-to-amazon-states-languages/)

> "Path.$": "States.Format('{}', $.item_id)"

the above works for me.

```json
{
  "Parameters": {
    "foo.$": "States.Format('Hello, {} {}', $.firstName, $.lastName)"
  }
}
```

So as you shared your URL path is something like `api.com/item/{id}`

> "Path.$": "States.Format('item/{}', $.item_id)"

Should also work.

The other I see is something like this, `Generate random ID` generates output like below:

```json
{
 "apipath": "item/",
 "item_id": "1213"
}
```

```json
"Path.$": "States.Format($.apipath, $.item_id)"
```

[Intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions-states)